# A quick regex thing

Tags: regex

```
<img src=​"http:​/​/​Some_image.png" alt=​"somethingIdonotneed"
```

Task: Group only the image bit (`src="this stuff.png"`), ignore the rest

Also, for some reason, in the HTML where I found this, there was no `</img>`. I thought all tags closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
/img[^>]+?(src\s*=\s*\"[^\"]*\")/i
```

You should get the first group.

Comment: -1 This will pick out all `src` matches, not just the ones in `img` tags.

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix here is

```
/img\s+(src="[^"]+")/
```

I highly recommend you don't use regex to parse HTML though.

---

Also, this is a [list of self-closing ("void") tags](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements). I.e., they do not require a `</...>` closing tag.

```
<area>
<base>
<basefont>
<br>
<col>
<command>
<embed>
<hr>
<input>
<img>
<keygen>
<link>
<meta>
<param>
<source>
<track>
<wbr>
```

Comment: The regex will capture all of the img tag, you need to get the first group of the regex.

Comment: @user1915496 how did you test?

Comment: This presupposes that the HTML is well-formed. If there is an `img` tag without a `src` attribute, this will grab the next `src` attribute from the next unrelated tag which has one, or from non-markup text. This can be fixed with a more constrained regex, but as others have pointed out, the proper fix is to parse HTML with a proper tool, not with regular expressions.

Comment: @tripleee, i tighted it up a little bit with `/img\s+.../`

Comment: @maček This doesn't match `<img id="abc" src="http://Some_image.png" alt="somethingIdonotneed"`

Comment: @prageeth, as I said, a DOM parser will provide a much more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will capture (whole, no groups) what you want:

```
(?<=<img )src="[^"]+"
```